# Can I use readfile() with videos in php?

Tags: php, html, laravel, video-streaming, html5-video

I looking for a way to protect my videos other than DRM, So I'm trying to use sessions instead of the direct link for the video, then I check it and if the session is true I run the video with fopen/readfile().

But the video can't be seed , it just work in life time like in this example:

[Here is a link from the site I work on.](http://www.okilyacademy.com/test/)

**Can I use any thing to make it seekable?**

```
    $file = base_path(). '/uploads/test.mp4';

    $size = File::size($file);
    $myfile = fopen($file, 'rb');

    echo fread($myfile, $size);
```

Comment: Better way is use route for stream the video and use it

Comment: And how is that ?

Comment: Just create a route and wrap your video fetching code into it and call that route into your `<source src="">`. Let me know if you need the complete code

Comment: That is what I really did!
`<source src="{{route('get-video')}}">`

And the code in this route the code in the post

Answer (score 0):

*Your route like*:

```
Route::get('get-video/{videoName}', 'YourController@getVideo')->name('getVideo');
```

*Your controller code like:*

```
public function getVideo($videoName)
{

    $fileContents = Storage::disk('local')->get("uploads/".$videoName);
    $response = Response::make($fileContents, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', "video/mp4");
    return $response;
}
```

*Your view like:*

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="{{ route('getVideo', 'test.mp4')  }}" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Also you need add below line into your root `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
```

NOTE: after this change still you facing issue with audio then need put below lines into `.htaccess` too:

```
Add type video/ogg .ogv 
Add type audio/ogg .oga
```

Comment: @ahmedyasser: Check this answer and let me know

Comment: I just wrote your code in my directory files and [Here is the result](http://www.okilyacademy.com/test/).

the same problem is on

Comment: Ok, given `500 Internal Server Error` means there is some problem at code. can you please debug it

Comment: Also I found `No video with supported format and MIME type found` means you need to allow this type of video using .htaccess at your root directory:

`AddType video/mp4 .mp4`

Comment: @ahmedyasser: Any result?

Comment: Oh sorry I was trying many things else, but now I Wrote your code again.

[Check it out and tell me what the problem is please](http://www.okilyacademy.com/test)

Comment: Have you setup `.htaccess` as described?

Comment: Got the solution?

Comment: @ahmedyasser: Provide the result please?

Comment: This is my .htaccess
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Any thing missed ?

Comment: `# Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    AddType video/mp4 .mp4`

I added it, could you check the video?

Comment: I think the problem is stay still